# Recursive iterate by nested objects with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested

Here is JSON with nested objects with not constant nesting level

```
{
    "level": 2,
    "title": "Subcat_in_cat2",
    "url": "subcat_in_cat2_url",
    "id": 5,
    "parent": {
      "level": 1,
      "title": "Cat2",
      "url": "cat2_url",
      "id": 2,
      "parent": {
        "level": 0,
        "title": "Cat1",
        "url": "cat1_url",
        "id": 1,
        "vertical_order": 0
      },
      "vertical_order": 0
    },
    "vertical_order": 0
}
```

How to iterate objects for creating breadcrumbs from this data like this:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="cat1">Cat1</a></li>
    <li><a href="cat2">Cat2</a></li>
    <li><a href="subcat_in_cat2_url">Subcat_in_cat2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Structure is all backwards. Should have parents at top level, children nested inside. Much easier to use arrays also for root data and nested children

Comment: @charlietfl You right, but there is no opportunity to change structure of json data on server. I have to use this one.

Comment: Then need more information on how this is being used. Is it being loaded each time a new breadcrumb is needed or is data shown a small part of bigger object?

Comment: This is a part of project. Actually, as you propose, I change a data structure to array - this is what about was my another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477576/convert-json-with-nested-objects-to-list-array-in-js)

Answer (score 0):

With Angular JS, you would have to do this, assuming that your JSON object is stored in $scope.categories:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb" ng-repeat="cat in categories">
   <li><a href="cat.url">{{cat.title}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: unfortunately this solution does not work as expected.

Comment: What error do you get from Angular in the JS console?

Comment: I changed data structure to [another type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477576/convert-json-with-nested-objects-to-list-array-in-js) and used an approach similar to written above.