# Convert JSON with nested objects to list array in JS

Tags: javascript, json

How nested objects from JSON data

```
{
    "title": "Sub sub cat",
    "url": "sub_sub_cat",
    "parent": {
      "title": "Sub сat",
      "url": "sub_cat",
      "parent": {
        "title": "Cat",
        "url": "cat",
      }
    }
}
```

convert to array of objects like this:

```
[   
    {"title": "Sub sub cat","url": "sub_sub_cat"},
    {"title": "Sub сat","url": "sub_cat"},
    {"title": "Cat","url": "cat"}
]
```

level of nested objects may be different
I try to solve it, but [receive](http://jsfiddle.net/4mesh09a/) not what I need

Comment: whats your parent vaule of the json code i.e. `parent.title` etc

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Recursion would work very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use recursion:

```js
var original_data = {
    "title": "Sub sub cat",
    "url": "sub_sub_cat",
    "parent": {
      "title": "Sub сat",
      "url": "sub_cat",
      "parent": {
        "title": "Cat",
        "url": "cat",
      }
    }
};
/*
 * This first function creates an empty array, launches the recursion, and returns it
 */
function convertData(data){
    var new_data = [];
    convertDataAux(data, new_data);
    return new_data;
}

/*
 * This one adds the relevant data to the array "n", recursively
 */
function convertDataAux(d,n){
    if(d && d.title && d.url){ n.push({ title : d.title, url : d.url }); }
    Object.keys(d).forEach(function(key){
        if(key !== 'title' && key !== 'url'){
            convertDataAux(d[key],n);
        }
    });
}
// Now, just call the first function
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify( convertData(original_data) );
```